# Rewriting a second-order nonlinear ode in first-order system - how?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I wanna show that

> $y''+\alpha \sin(y)=f(x)$  with  $y(a)=y_0$ and $y'(a)=y_1$

has got an unique solution.
I wanted to rewrite this ODE in an ODE system of first order and than apply picard-lindelöf on each row.

My problem is that I don't know how to rewrite this in an ODE of first order because of $\sin(y)$ and because it's non-homogeneous.

I thought of substituting $z:=y'$ than we've got:
$z'+\alpha \sin(y) = f(x)$ and if we look at the homogeneous ODE $z'+\alpha \sin(y) = 0$ we get $z(y)= \alpha \cos(y)+c_0$ as a solution.

Substituting back we get  $y'(x)= \alpha \cos(y(x))+c_0$

I've read that we can rewrite this equation in $Ax=b$ with $x=\pmatrix{x \\ \dot x}$ and $b=\pmatrix{0 \\f(t)}$ , but I'm not sure about the matrix I guess it's something like $A=\pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ -\alpha \sin & 0}$.

Any hints or good books to recommend?

Comment: @Moo: how did you get there?

Comment: Then you could also split off the linear part of the sine to get $$X' = \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ -α & 0}\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2} + \pmatrix{0  \\ \alpha (x_1-\sin x_1)}.$$ This separation of the linear part however gives no additional insight into the structure of the first order system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the step
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\pmatrix{y(x)\\z(x)}=F(x,y(x),z(x))=\pmatrix{z(x)\\-α\sin(y(x))+f(x)}
$$
is correct. The integration attempts after that are wrong as they wildly mix integration variables.

Note that $F(x,y,z)=(z,-α\sin(y)+f(x))^T$ is continuously differentiable in $(y,z)$ and even globally Lipschitz in these variables.